# About normal form of an element of a free group

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Let $G=\langle S\rangle$ be a finitely generated free group with at least two generators. Let $g_0\in G$ has the normal form $g_0= s_rs_{r-1}\ldots s_1$.

In a paper, author claimed that for every $t\in G$, there is $v\in G$, where $v$ is  the element of minimal length,  such that $t=vw$ for the some $w=tv^{-1}$ of the form $w=s_js_{j-1}\ldots s_1(s_rs_{r-1}\ldots s_1)^k$ or $w=s_{r-j+1}^{-1}\ldots s_r^{-1}(s_rs_{r-1}\ldots s_1)^{-k}$ for some $k\geq 0$ and $1\leq j\leq r$.

Please help me to know it.

Is it true that for every $t\in G$, there is a unique $v\in G$  with minimal length,  such that $t=vw$?

Let for $t\in G$, element $v\in G$ has a minimal length such that $t=vw$. What can say about $st\in G$ for $s\in S$. We know that there exist $v'\in G$ and $w'\in G$ with $st=v'w'$. Is it true that the $w'=w$ and $v'=sv$?

Comment: Which paper are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun,  Shadowing for actions of some finitely
generated groups page  348-349

Comment: It looks like the passage you quoted has an error: $t=vw$ and $w=tv^{-1}$ are not equivalent. I can see that this error occurred in the original paper. While I cannot attest to know what the authors' intents were, I've written an answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'll make a guess at how to correct an error in the original paper:

> Find the shortest $v$ such that $t=vw$, where $w=v^{-1}t$ has one of the two forms given.

Given the normal form $t = t_k t_{k-1} ... t_1$, to find $v$ you simply search one-at-a-time through all factorizations of the normal form of $t$ into two words
$$t = \underbrace{(t_k t_{k-1} ... t_j)}_{v_j} \underbrace{(t_{j-1} ... t_1)}_{w_j}
$$
Starting with $j=k$ and working downward, examine each $w_j$ to see if it has one of the two required forms. Stop when you've found the first such $j$. The word you seek is $v=v_j$. It's possible you never find any such $j$, in which case $t=vw$ where $w$ is the empty word.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. What can say about second part of my question:

Comment: Let for $t\in G$, element $v\in G$ has a minimal length such that $t=vw$. What can say about $st\in G$ for $s\in S$. We know that there exist $v'\in G$ and $w'\in G$ with $st=v'w'$. Is it true that the $w'=w$ and $v'=sv$?

Comment: It can fail if $v$ is the empty word and $t=w$, because there's only one generator $s$ you can stick in front of a word $w$ that has one of the two forms given, in order that $w'=sw$ also has one of those two forms. When $v$ is nonempty then its true, by maximality of the construction.